# pH of buffer solution

Tags: acid-base

Why does ammonium formate has less pH than ammonium acetate . Even though both the salts have the same structure..

I thought that dissociation of acetic acid and formic acid would have a role in this phenomenon, and I thought that acetic acid forms dimer but I don't know if formic acid forms a dimer or not. Do these things have a role in their pH.?

Comment: Yes, formic acids forms a dimer (nearly all carboxylic acids do), though probably not in the dilute water solution. No, this is not important. Just look up the pKa of both acids.

Comment: pKa of acetic acid is 4.8 and pKa of formic acid is 3.8 . And what factors make them different.

Comment: Well, they are different compounds, so it's only natural for them to differ in everything, including pKa. Now, which of the two is stronger? and hence which is more prone to hydrolysis?

Comment: I think formic acid is stronger than acetic acid so, it will hydrolyse more. Is that correct@ Ivan neretin

Comment: You have it backwards: salts of stronger acids hydrolyze _less_.

Comment: Got that salts of stronger acid hydrolyse less than salts of weaker acids, and same will be the case with bases . Thank you@ Ivan Neretin.